# Difficulty achieving parallelization when creating video streams from multiple USB cameras in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, webrtc, usb-camera

I am trying to capture images from six USB cameras using JavaScript (chrome , windows). I have implemented three functions: one to retrieve the list of connected cameras, another to initialize video streams, and a third to capture images from these streams. Despite using async/await and the map function, I am facing an issue with the parallelization of stream creation.

The problem is that the time it takes to create the streams does not show any improvement when compared to a sequential approach. It seems like the stream creation is not happening in parallel as intended.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```js
    // Function to get the list of connected cameras
    const getCameraList = async () => {
      const devices = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
      return devices.filter(device => device.kind === 'videoinput');
    }

    // Function to initialize video streams
    const initializeStreams = async (camera) => {
      const constraints = {
        audio: false,
        video: { deviceId: camera.deviceId },
      };
      return await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
    }

    // Function to capture images from streams
    const captureImages = async (streams) => {
      const result = await Promise.all(streams.map(async (stream) => {
        const videoTrack = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
        if (!videoTrack) return;

        const imageCapture = new ImageCapture(videoTrack);
        const blob = await imageCapture.takePhoto({});
        return blob;
      }))
    }

    // Main function to orchestrate the process
    const main = async () => {
      try {
        const cameras = await getCameraList();

        // The issue is here: parallelization is not effective
        const streams = await Promise.all(cameras.map(initializeStreams));

        // same issue here: parallelization is not effective
        await captureImages(streams);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("An error occurred:", error);
      }
    }

    main();
```

And here are the log results for initializing streams:

```
13:40:05.921  Cam3: 6524.796142578125 ms
13:40:11.737  Cam6: 12340.535888671875 ms
13:40:13.050  Cam5: 13652.81201171875 ms
13:40:18.869  Cam1: 19471.5029296875 ms
13:40:24.712  Cam2: 25313.91796875 ms
13:40:30.521  Cam4: 31123.049072265625 ms


13:40:30.521  load streams: 31124.97021484375 ms
```

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to achieve effective parallelization during the creation of video streams. Thank you!

Comment: There’s no “parallel” in JS unless you’re using workers/etc.

Comment: When making API calls in JavaScript using `async`, `await`, and `Promise.all`, the language does not wait to receive results from the first request before initiating the second API call. I anticipated a similar behavior when attempting to create streams for cameras, as these operations resemble requests to initialize streams  @DaveNewton

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything in your code that should prevent multiple streams initialising at the same time.  Are all these camera's identical, it's maybe some driver issues with the camera device driver only able to initialise one camera at a time.  Also over 6 seconds to initialise the first camera seems excessive.  Are all these cameras connected to the same USB via a HUB maybe, and there is bandwidth issues.  If you say connected 1 camera directly to 1 USB on PC, and another USB on the PC, and you did 2 cameras do you get the same issue?

Comment: @DaveNewton  Javascript is not parallel, but the browser certainly is, and using `async` is a way to harness it from JS.  And of course using webcams with `async` should be fine here.   Looking at the OP's code, I'm not seeing any serialised `async` code causing the web cams not to initialise concurrently.  I just wonder if the OP's issue is environmental.

Comment: @Keith It's not parallel unless some sort of worker is used.

Comment: @EhsanNazeri If there's only a single camera hooked up how long does it take? It will be trickly to diagnose w/o direct access.

Comment: @DaveNewton  You didn't read my comment properly.

Comment: I have tested on different computers and laptops with different cameras (all cameras are the same brand and model). The results are consistent. It appears that there is a problem at the OS level. Windows uses the `Media Foundation API` to create streams by default. However, there is an alternative way to retrieve data from a USB camera using DirectShow in Windows. To enable this, you need to change the `chrome://flags/#enable-media-foundation-video-capture`  flag in Chrome. When using DirectShow, the streams are created in parallel. but I need to use the default Api. @Keith @DaveNewton

Comment: @Keith ... The browser isn't parallel unless some sort of worker is used. Using async/await doesn't change the implementation of JS, just how it looks in the code.

Comment: @DaveNewton No the browser is parallel,  It's Javascript that's NOT parallel.  Anyway it's irrelevant, as using a worker to initialise multiple camera's would be pointless.

Comment: @EhsanNazeri  Yeah, I did wonder if things were OS based,.  Unfortunately not much you can do about this in Javascript, even using a worker wouldn't help.

Comment: @Keith We may be using the word differently. async/await has nothing to do with parallelization and user code, unless it's explicitly using workers, isn't parallel. Whether or not it makes sense to init cameras in workers is orthogonal, it might make sense, it might not. *(I probably wouldn't **bother** doing it in workers, assuming it'd work, but that's how you'd get parallelization in the browser.)*

Comment: @DaveNewton  I've never said `async/await` is parallelisation, I've said now a fair few times, the Browser, Javascript is not the Browser.   For example, each TAB in my version of Chrome on Linux, takes about 15 threads.  A worker is handy for running multiple copies of JS at the same time, but this is not the issue the OP is having, there is no Javascript bottleneck here.

Comment: @Keith I didn't say there was. You said: "Javascript is not parallel, but the browser certainly is, and using async is a way to harness it from JS." This is incorrect. The part that is incorrect is "using async is a way to harness it from JS", not the part about "browsers using threads". A browser window/tab's user code isn't parallel unless explicitly coded to be so--my whole point was that the OP is talking about parallelism, which is not happening here.

Comment: @DaveNewton  `"using async is a way to harness it from JS"`  Eh!!!,  I don't think you get what I'm saying here.  I'll repeat just in case you missed it, Javascript is not parallel we agree, but the browser is.  If you re-read what I said again, can you not grasp what I mean by the term `harness` ????

Comment: @Keith I do not, because async/await harnesses parallelism in neither JS nor the browser.

Comment: @DaveNewton  Yes it does, the browser has multiple threads, like I pointed out earlier.  You request an `async` operation in Javascript.  A thread or possibly overlapped / IO event or IRQ in the `browser` processes said action.  Using `async` methods, like `async/await` / `callbacks`, is how you can `harness` said actions.  Because if it didn't work this way and you had to serialize say image downloads, it would feel rather slow.  Let's be clear again here, Javascript is single threaded, 100% agree on that, the browser is not.  Don't keep mixing up `browser` and `javascript` it's not the same.

Comment: @Keith You're still confusing terminology, but okay; you have way more time for this than I do.

Comment: @DaveNewton  Yeah, terminology can confuse things, but I'm not 100% sure what terminology you disagree on.  Is it the the term `harness`?, I thought that was a good word to use, the browser has multiple threads, a fair few of them waiting for commands from the JS engine, without the JS engine been able use `callback` / `Promise` / `async/await` etc, the JS engine would have to use some sort of blocking loop to receive results.  But by using `async/await` you can make the JS engine feel like it's multi-threaded, a bit like Windows 3.11 and it's cooperative multi-tasking.

Comment: @Keith Neither “feel like multithreading” nor “cooperative multitasking” are parallel, which is what I’ve been saying. Demoable by wrapping up anything parallelizable/CPU-bound in async/await/promises/callbacks. Async/await/etc avoids IO blocking the user/main thread, but it doesn’t parallelize it. Parallel has a specific meaning and w/o a different runtime, workers/native threads/etc it’s not parallel—it’s more like machine-guided co-op and **feels** parallel because the mechanics handle it.

Comment: @DaveNewton  I know why it feels parallel, I pretty much explained it in my previous comment.  And like I keep saying, the `browser` is parallel, and again as I keep saying I know JavaScript is NOT.  IOW: Like I said, the `async/await` helps the single threaded Javscript runtime `harness` the multi-threaded aspect of the Browser.   None of that terminology is incorrect as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: @Keith Okay. Carry on.

Answer (score 0):

Some worker or any Video SDK will be required for achieving parallelisation, one such website is videosdk.live